# Custom Datetimepicker that will allow to enable/disable certain dates

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, datetimepicker

I need to develop a custom `DateTimePicker` that will allow me to enable/disable certain dates from the calendar for allowing/disallowing user to select them.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What did you try? Show some code.

Comment: there is an example in techpower -
http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/a-custom-datetimepicker-control-in-c.70925/#post-968501

but it needs a custom month calendar control-
http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/a-modified-monthcalendar-control-in-c.70554/#post-962455

but i have a query in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set blackdays in the DatePicker, maybe that helps.

See documentation [DatePicker.BlackoutDates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.blackoutdates%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: gray out the dates seems not possible, see this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214940/monthcalendar-disable-days (can't answer above cause of reputations)

Comment: hmm, I have decided to use wpf control in winforms :) thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `ValueChanged` event to handle manually your date validation. See [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Something like this will to the trick:

```
private void DateTimePicker_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var selectedDate = this.DateTimePicker.Value;
    if (this.DateIsForbidden(selectedDate))
    {
        var forcedDate = this.GetAllowedDate(selectedDate);
        this.DateTimePicker.Value = forcedDate;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Date {0} is not allowed. {1} selected instead", selectedDate, forcedDate));
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but we want to gray out the dates so that that user wont select them and no value change event occurs, the user should be able to identify it is disabled.